# Use the method of minimal counterexample to prove

Tags: real-analysis

Use the method of minimal counterexample to prove

If $r$ is a nonzero real number such that $r+\dfrac{1}{r}$ is integer then $r^n+\dfrac{1}{r^n}$ is integer.

How to prove this by using method of minimal counterexample?

I know how to solve this by strong induction. Are they both the same?

Answer (score 1):

So, you know that $r+\dfrac{1}{r}$ is integer. Suppose that there exists $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $r^n+\dfrac{1}{r^n}$ is not integer and pick $m$ the least one such that $r^m+\dfrac{1}{r^m}$ is not integer. Then, certainly, $m>1$. Now, you only need to prove that there exists $1\leq k<m$ such that $r^k+\dfrac{1}{r^k}$ is not integer, that is,
$$r^m+\dfrac{1}{r^m}\notin\mathbb Z\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \exists1\leq k<m: r^k+\dfrac{1}{r^k}\notin \mathbb Z,$$ which will give a contradiction with the minimality of $m$.

But note that the step
$$r^m+\dfrac{1}{r^m}\notin\mathbb Z\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ \exists1\leq k<m: r^k+\dfrac{1}{r^k}\notin \mathbb Z,$$
is precisely the contrapositive of the induction step:
$$
r^k+\dfrac{1}{r^k}\in\mathbb Z,\ \ \forall 1\leq k<m\ \ \ \Rightarrow\ \ \ r^m+\dfrac{1}{r^m}\in\mathbb Z.
$$
So, once you proved it by induction, you may now easily prove it by the minimal counterexample method.